# Is there a way to enable interactive search in properties window?

Tags: android-studio

I just started to use Android Studio and wondering if there is a way to search interactively in property window.[image]

I mean like Xcode does. (It's not a properties, though.) [image]

Is there a plugin or configuration for the function like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no filter like in Xcode, but if you start typing property name the selection will jump to the first match and the rest of the matches will be highlighted.

Comment: Thanks! This is more than I expected!

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio actually has a search tool for properties similar to the one in Xcode.  But it's implemented in a very unusual and un-intuitive way. Which makes it hard to find.

In Android Studio version 1.5.1, you have to click either on the 'Properties' header or any property-name below the header, and then you need to start typing the property you want, even though there is no text-box or any other indication that your typing will produce any effect.

When you do this, then a text-box appears with the characters you've typed in.  And Android Studio highlights all the properties that contain your character sequence.  You can then look only at the highlighted properties to find the one you want.